# CI Jenkins Permission denied on .sh file

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am running into an issue which I've been researching on for days. Having given up, I've decided to ask here.

I am trying to fix a permission denied CI exception. The error below occurs when it is trying to run a .sh script.

```
+ find . -name '*.sh' -type f -exec chmod +x '{}' ';'
+ scripts/run_ci.py --push-merge
/tmp/hudson1523957012397738349.sh: line 3: scripts/run_ci.py: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I tried adding 'chmod' command inside CI's 'Execute Shell' but it didn't work. Below is exactly how I've written it.

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

In the error log however, the brackets and the semi-colon is executed with '   ' and backlash completely disappeared.

Additional note: I have also tried adding "" in the command and still receives error such as this:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x "{}" "\;"
```

My question is:

1. Could it be the '' sign that failed the command?
2. If so, how do I ensure the '' is not added into the command?
3. If not, how can I fix this permission issue for CI?

Comment:

I can't comment down there for some reason but I will upvote your comments later when I am able to but thank you for pointing that out that the .py doesn't get the permission changed and the list dir thing as well.

I greatly appreciate it since I've been struggling with it for days now. TT.TT

Comment: Add some "ls" and other informational commands to tour script so you can see what is happening in there. "ls -al" for a start. If you are generating commands then do an echo of the same string.

Comment: The error says that the permissions on `run_ci.py` are wrong. Your `find` command only adds execute permission to `.sh` files, not `.py` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the permissions on `run_ci.py` are wrong. Your `find` command only adds execute permission to `.sh` files, not `.py` files.
                    – Barmar